# How do you figure out the decoder inputs for a memory expansion?

Tags: memory, ram

How do you know what the two inputs will be for this 2-to-4 decoder? Also, what changes would be made to the circuit if the 2 data lines are not the same?

The original problem:

[image]

[image]

I drew the circuit, but I'm confused about the two things mentioned prior.

Comment: 1) Normally they will be the next highest address lines above those connected to the memories. That gives one contiguous memory space. 2) WHAT two data lines? This question makes no sense : each memory has 16 data lines and you need 32.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you would drive your two decoder inputs with A15 and A16 for splitting 128K into 4 - 32K segments.  You'll drive your 32K chips with A0-A14.

Comment: This clicked with me after watching a few visuals by Indian youtubers; the next thing is that I believe the number of chips I have is wrong? 128/32 is 4 and 32/16 is 2 so 2*4 would be 8 chips; i'm not sure if i'm calculating the number of chips needed the right way? and my input/output data should've been 32 in my original post

Comment: scratch that, the input/output data are fine the way they are